# Is $\rho:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ a covering map of the circumference by itself?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm given the following map $\rho:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ such that $\rho(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ and I'm asked to prove whether it is a covering map.

Giving some values it seems like every point has two preimages distributed around the circumference so I think this is a good candidate for a 2-sheeted covering.

My strategy uses the fact that the spaces are Hausdorff and compact and therefore I just need to prove that $\rho$ is a local homeomorphism. However, the explicit map makes it difficult to prove the local homeomorphism condition. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about $S^1$ embedded in $\Bbb C$ by $(x,y)\mapsto x+iy$.
Then $\rho$ becomes the squaring map $z\mapsto z^2$, or equivalently
$e^{it}\mapsto e^{2it}$. The inverse image of an open set $\{e^{it}:t_1<t<t_2\}$ is $\{e^{it}:t_1/2<t<t_2/2\}\cup
\{e^{it}:t_1/2+\pi<t<t_2/2+\pi\}$.